# Group items from the first time + certain time period

Tags: sql

I want to group orders from the same customer if they happen within 10 minutes of the first order, then find the next first order and group them and so on.

Ex:

```
   Customer group  orders
   6        1      3
            2      4,5
            3      8
   7        1      9,10
            2      11,12
            3      13


    id  customer time
    3   6   2021-05-12 12:14:22.000000
    4   6   2021-05-12 12:24:24.000000
    5   6   2021-05-12 12:29:16.000000
    8   6   2021-05-12 13:01:40.000000
    9   7   2021-05-14 12:13:11.000000
    10  7   2021-05-14 12:20:01.000000
    11  7   2021-05-14 12:45:00.000000
    12  7   2021-05-14 12:48:41.000000
    13  7   2021-05-14 12:58:16.000000
    18  9   2021-05-18 12:22:13.000000
    25  15  2021-05-18 13:44:02.000000
    26  16  2021-05-17 09:39:02.000000
    27  16  2021-05-18 19:38:43.000000
    28  17  2021-05-18 15:40:02.000000
    29  18  2021-05-19 15:32:53.000000
    30  18  2021-05-19 15:45:56.000000
    31  18  2021-05-19 16:29:09.000000
    34  15  2021-05-24 15:45:14.000000
    35  15  2021-05-24 15:45:14.000000
    36  19  2021-05-24 17:14:53.000000
```

Here is what I have currently, I think that it is currently not grouping by customer  when `case when d.StartTime > dateadd(minute, 10, c.first_time)`  so it compares StartTime of all orders for all customers.

```
with 
data as (select Customer,StartTime,Id, row_number() over(partition by Customer order by StartTime) rn from orders t),
cte as (
     select d.*, StartTime as first_time 
     from data d
     where rn = 1
     union all 
     select d.*, 
         case when d.StartTime > dateadd(minute, 10, c.first_time)
             then d.StartTime
             else c.first_time
         end
     from cte c 
    inner join data d on d.rn = c.rn + 1
 )
select c.*, dense_rank() over(partition by Customer order by first_time) grp 
from cte c;'
```

I have two databases (MySQL & SQL Server) having similar schema so either would work for me.

Comment: *if they happen after 10 minutes* - this doesn't agree with your example groups and would group all of custome r#6 after the first order, should this be *within* 10 minutes? And is it after the *first* order, or *any* order? all of customer #6 orders are after 10 minutes since the first order. "first" assumed to be the earliest.

Comment: @Stu After the first order add 10 min and group whatever in the range, then the next first order add 10 min and group whatever in the range. If it was after any order I would have used LAG window function but here I need to keep track of the first one.

Comment: MySql and SQL Server use different column datatypes and so cannot possibly have the same schema.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn here datatypes do not have any effect

Comment: It is not just the datatypes that are different, but the sql implementation as well. Please make up your mind which of the two products you eish to target.

Comment: @Shadow actually we migrated from MySql to Sql Server recently, that is why I don't have a problem with which query is available because I can use both at least for this moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following on SQL Server:

```
SELECT customer,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY grp) AS group_no, 
       STRING_AGG(id, ',') AS orders
FROM
  (
    SELECT id,customer, [time], 
      (DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER), [time])/60)/10 grp
    FROM orders
  ) T
GROUP BY customer, grp
ORDER BY customer
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8R_9LYgp).

According to your posted requirement, you are trying to divide the period between the first order date and the last order date into groups (or let's say time frames) each one is 10 minutes long.

What I did in this query: for each customer order, find the difference between the order date and *the minimum date* (first customer order date) in seconds and then divide it by 10 to get it's time frame number. i.e. for a difference = 599s the frame number = 599/60 =9m /10 = 0. for a difference = 620s the frame number = 620/60 =10m /10 = 1.

After defining the correct groups/time frames for each order you can simply use the `STRING_AGG` function to get the desired output. *Noting that the `STRING_AGG` function applies to SQL Server 2017 (14.x) and later*.